# Silverlight on client only works as local admin

Tags: silverlight, iis, silverlight-4.0

I have client who has installed our Silverlight app.  The app works fine when running from the IIS server.  It also works from a client machine - but only if the user is logged in as local admin.  If they log in with a non-admin account, they get a blank screen where the silverlight app should be.

When I look in the server logs I see that the XAP is being blocked, getting 401 response code.

Any suggestions?  It feels like this has to do with accounts, which I am no expert in.

Comment: Is this an Out of Browser app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably something wrong in the IIS security settings.

Is [Anonymous authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780334%28WS.10%29.aspx) activated in IIS?

Comment: Yes, they had hosed the security settings.  After rebuilding the machine all was working fine.  No idea what they set, but seems to be fine at the moment.